# how to show Persian text received from a web service in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, nusoap, persian

I'm new to Web Services, but I made one like this:

```
require_once "lib/nusoap.php";

function welcome($name)
{
   return $name . "خوش آمدید";
}

$server = new soap_server();

$server->configureWSDL("testWebService", "urn:testWebService");

$server->register("welcome",
 array("name" => "xsd:string"),
 array("return" => "xsd:string"),
 "urn:testWebService",
 "urn:testWebService#welcome",
 "rpc",
 "encoded",
 "for user login check");
```

the "welcome" function returns a string that is partially in the Persian language.
I want to use this web service function in my C# application. I've successfully added the web service to my solution in VS and i tried to use it like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(myWebsrvice.welcome("Mansoor"));
```

It runs fine but doesn't show the Persian part of the text correctly. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: you should use unicode encoding from assembly 
`System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString()`

Comment: `Encoding.Unicode.GetString() ` gets byte[] as input how should i use this ?

Comment: Please release out code that you have tried to check

Comment: I thought that I should change it to byte[] and change it back to String so i tried this: `Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myWebsrvice.welcome("Mansoor")))` and all the combinations between `Unicode`,`ASCII` and `UTF8`

Comment: Edit your question post and write your c# code. That could be useful

Answer (score 4):

First add this to your php code and check your client side

```
$server->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
$server->decode_utf8 = false;
```